# Element not taking up all the space when width and height is set to 100%

Tags: html, css

The red `#container` element doesn't seem to take up all the available space in the document, even when it's width is set to 100%. There seems to be some extra padding in the `html` element, but even when I set it's padding to 0 it's still there.

How could I fix this? Thanks in advance.

### Demo code:

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='container'></div>
</body>
```

[JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/4vwfqgL5/1)

Comment: you only have this margin in most of the "snippet", "fiddle" to the body, on a normal html page, you wont have that. So just add `margin:0;` to your `body`

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `padding: 0` and `margin: 0` to:

```
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Answer does not show the suggested changes to the code in the code block.

Comment: It clearly states what the OP has to do, simple english interpretation, hence the `to:`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `margin: 0px;` to your CSS:

```
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Seems to be working here:

https://jsfiddle.net/k2boqeLt/